# Filter-based user authentication for Vaadin 10+ without Spring

Tags: authentication, jakarta-ee, vaadin

I am looking towards implementing user login/authentication for my Vaadin application, but I stumbled upon not finding actual resources for implementing form- and filter-based user authentication in modern Vaadin (Vaadin 10+ AKA Vaadin Flow) without using Spring.

I think I can come up with some custom solution but because of my current lack of deep understanding of Vaadin internals I may expose some hard-to-find vulnerabilities or not handle some corner-cases. So I'm looking for a guide/sample code on how to do this properly.

Still all the stuff I was able to find is either outdated (references Vaadin 8, 7 and even earlier) or is based on Spring framework which I'm not using.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20960996/376066) is a most comprehensive answer I was able to find so far, but it lacks actual details for my case.